# Alternative for sharing data between components - without subscribing

Tags: angular

In Angular 2, 
We are using 2 components - HomeComponent and LoginComponent in my case.
We have a requirement to maintain the code readability and to modularize the code. Also, each component does specific function. In this, while sharing data between components, we share the data between service members and the variable is watched for any data change.

The problem is, for the code:

```
this.loginService.profile$.subscribe(
        tempData => {
            this.setProfile(tempData);
        }
    );
```

the tempData will have the value after the Data is being fetched from the server and set in HomeComponent to the subscribed variable - *profile$*. So on updation or changing the variable, **this.outputdata** inturn, causes the function doBusinessLogic() to call each and everytime and this inturn makes the call to the server each time on the variable changes. this is affecting the performance.

So,
1. Instead of subscribing the variable to get data from another component, is there any other approach to handle this?
2. How to handle watch Item in my case?

*Angular 2 -*

**LoginComponent : login.component.ts**

```
@Component({
        selector: 'login',
        templateUrl: 'app/login.html' })

    export class LoginComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    //Declaring Variables:

    ngOnInit(){
    //Any other Alternative other than Subscribing the data ?
    this.loginService.profile$.subscribe(
            tempData => {
                this.doBusinessLogic(tempData);
            }
        );

        public doBusinessLogic(data : any){
            //Do Various Business Logic in this function and Do Server Calls.
        }
    }


    }
```

**HomeComponent : home.component.ts**

```
@Component({
        selector: 'home',
        templateUrl: 'app/home.html' })

    export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    //Declaring Variables:

    ngOnInit(){
        this.loadInitData();
    }

    loadInitData(){

        //Fetch Data From Server and stored in variable - loadProfileData;
        const loadProfileData = this.userService.fetchProfileData();
        loadProfileData.map((res: Response) => {
            return res.json();
        })
        .subscribe(
        res => {
            //Set the value in the shared service variable to use it in another Component 
         this.outputdata = res;
            this.loginService.setProfile(this.outputdata);
        });

    }

    }
```

**LoginService : login.service.ts**

```
 @Injectable()
    export class UserService {

        // Observing Admin Business Unit User Profile
        private profileSub = new Subject<any>();
        profile$ = this.profileSub.asObservable();
        profile: any;

        setProfile(userData: any) {
            this.profile = userData;
            this.profileSub.next(userData);
        }
        getProfile() {
            return this.profile;
        }

        fetchProfileData() : Observable<any> {
            //Get Profile Data From Server
        }

    }
```

EDITS: this.outputdata - the variable - which tends to be altered based on business requirements. So, on making the variable changes, this tends to invoke the server call in Login Component. But the point here is, the modification in this.outputdata does not have anything to do with fetching the data for LoginComponent.

Comment: setProfile is setting the value and I guess it wlll be called on login only. Why there would be performance issue here ?

Comment: Technically the code is right every time home component is initialized setProfile will be called, and when set profile is called doBusinessLogic will be called. One way can be if( ! loadProfileData) only then loadInitData(). Also it will be helpful if you state the business requirement. You may also store the data in sessionstorage/localstorage from homecomponent, and can check if data present inside storage then don't call the userservice, even on page refresh. On browser close the data can be removed manually/automatically. This way when page is loaded userservice will fetch fresh records

Comment: @Sunil Singh, edited few part of code. The variable , this.outputdata tends to be changed during the business logic application everytime. This intends to call doBusinessLogic () everytime.

Comment: Why not use DinstinctUntilChanged in your login component? This way doBusinessLogic() is only called when the value changes from loginService?

Comment: What is the purpose of DinstinctUntilChanged ? @crooksey